# Hierarchical Queries in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical

Can I use 2 tables for hierachical queries?

Comment: Try looking at the Database Administrators community. You might be more likely to get an answer there. I googled the content of your question and found a question on the DBA community that might be just what you're looking for. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4264/hierarchical-query-from-two-tables

Comment: please provide your table structure, input and expected output

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can used two table for hierarchical queries. for that we need to join that two table and that we need to project that join as a single set of result and that on that single result set we apply that hierarchical queries.

Regards.